# Error 324 when signing in to PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I've been struggling with a frustrating problem for a few days and I'm being more and more confused; I can't login to `PHPMyAdmin` without receiving a *Web Error 324* after about thirty seconds. The communication between `MySQL` and PHPMyAdmin is working but the failed login is the problem. I'm suspecting the configuration of PHP but I'm not sure.

I'm running a web server with `Apache 2.0.64` with `PHP 5.2.17` on `Windows Server 2003` and I can run PHPINFO without problem.

I've reinstalled both Apache and PHP several times, but the problem is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like timeout drop after 30 seconds. What does Firebug says?

Comment: Nothing unusual what I can see. When I try to sign in with wrong credentials, PHPMyAdmin directly shows a error message. But when I'm trying with an account, such as root or a test account I've created, the page starts loading and ends up in a web error. Little frustrating...

Comment: Something in IIS `error.log` file? What does Firebug says?

Comment: Taken from access.log:
[[Client IP]] - - [21/Oct/2012:10:40:35 +0200] "POST /phpm/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 -

Nothing found in error.log

I haven't used Firebug before. What information do you want?

Comment: From Network section. all about hanging request. If it was reset by server, you'll see that.

Comment: This is what i see:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/88949320@N05/8108190801/in/photostream

Comment: Your request is really dropped by server by timeout (Aborted). In `access.log` or in `error.log` there should be records about `GET index.php?token=70...`. Search it and post. There is error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem with Chrome, you can try the solutions posted [here](http://www.roezer.com/fixing-chrome-bug-error-324-neterr_empty_response/). If your problem is in any browser, then you have to check a bit more the related logs. Start with the logs from apache, then, you can check, and post, the response headers that live http headers gives you (firefox addon).

Answer (score 0):

I've setup another web server now with the exact software environment and everything is running smooth on that one so there's probably something wrong with Windows. But I've to take that another day... Thank you for all support and help!